# How can I add a sticky footer to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I’m coding a mock messaging application in Swift Playgrounds for iPad. So far, I have a `UITableViewController` with a custom cell, whose background color changes every other cell. Now, I’d like to add a sticky footer of some kind to the bottom of the screen that will have a text field and a send button so that the user can send messages. I’m not quite sure how to approach this. Any ideas? Here’s what I have so far:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let textMessages = [
        "Here's my very first message",
        "I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap",
        "I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap, I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap, I'm going to message another long message that will word wrap",
        "Somejfjfidiskkejejsjsjsjdjjdj blah blah blah"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Messages"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        tableView.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_1")
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return textMessages.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 1{
            cell.messageLabel.text = textMessages[indexPath.row]
            //cell.setupConstraints(side: 1)
            cell.bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
            return cell
        }else{
            cell.messageLabel.text = textMessages[indexPath.row]
            //cell.setupConstraints(side: 0)
            cell.bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .blue
            return cell
        }
    }
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
    //        cell.textLabel?.text = "We want to provide a longer string that is actually going to wrap onto the next line and maybe even a third line."
    //        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
}

class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    let bubbleBackgroundView = UIView()
    var leadingAnchorConstant = CGFloat()

    func setupConstraints(side: Int){
        if side == 1{
            leadingAnchorConstant = frame.size.width - 176
        }else{
            leadingAnchorConstant = 32
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        bubbleBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bubbleBackgroundView)

        addSubview(messageLabel)
        //        messageLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        messageLabel.text = "We want to provide a longer string that is actually going to wrap onto the next line and maybe even a third line."
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // lets set up some constraints for our label
        let constraints = [messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 32),
                           messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32),
                           messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
                           messageLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),

                           bubbleBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.topAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

        //        messageLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for these tableview delegate methods to set up a custom footer:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "footer_cell") as! FooterCell
     // Set up cell
     let cell = UITableViewCell()
     cell.textLabel?.text = "Footer"
     cell.backgroundColor = .white
     return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
     return 40.0 // Set height of footer
}
```

You can use custom tableview cells the same way you use them in cellForRow - I just set it up with simple default cells to produce a working sample - you can also create UIView() to return to this method

By default it will stick to bottom of screen above tableview - if this isn't the case or you want it to stick to bottom of table you can change this setting in attributes inspector if using storyboard:

[image]

Style - Plain -> Sticks to bottom of view on top of tableview

Style - Grouped -> Sticks to bottom of tableview no matter how tall

Although another option probably even better without the use of a footer is to use a  UITableView on UIViewController - this will give you the space to add your TextView, Buttons and whatever else you need directly on the View Controller under the UITableView

Left is UITableViewController - Right is UIViewController with UITableView

[image: Example]

Up to you how you want to play it but I'd recommend the second option to provide the most flexibility on a ViewController

Hope this helps!